# Axios is not passing cookies upon 302 redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, cookies, axios

I'm trying to implement an admin request submission class in node.js.
There are two API calls, one is Login and the second is Request Access (Both are forms).
I've managed to build these two API calls in Postman, however, I'm struggling with getting the same behavior in node.js. Probably because cookies are not passed correctly.

The login flow is:
Send POST request to *https://{{base_uri}}/hc/web/siteadminlogin/siteadmin/AdminAccess.jsp*
With form data and Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

The response from this call is 302 redirect that sets these two cookies:

`Set-Cookie: WSHumanClickWebSession=816d619eddd19ee46ac03bf88b381; path=/hc/web; secure; HttpOnly`

`Set-Cookie: WSHumanClickServer=z1-e-dnv6969; path=/hc/web; secure`

Then the redirect triggers a GET request to the following URL:
*https://{{base_uri}}/hc/web/siteadmin/siteadmin/AdminAccess.jsp?site={{form_data_site}}*

With the cookies from the initial POST response.

Postman handles cookie storage automatically, however, in Axios these cookies are not passed correctly to the 302 redirect. Causing the login to fail and return back to the login page.

This is what I have in node:

```
    const qs = require('qs');
    const data = qs.stringify({
        'user_name': 'user_name',
        'password': 'user_pass!!',
        'site_number': 'site_num',
        'But1':'Submit'
    });
    const config = {
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://base_uri/hc/web/siteadminlogin/siteadmin/AdminAccess.jsp',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        data : data,
        withCredentials: true,
    };
    try {
        const response = await axios(config);
        console.log(response.headers);
        console.log(response.data);
    }catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
```

It's either the form data is not being submitted correctly or the cookies are not being stored and passed between the requests.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: I have a similar problem too, for me it is exhibiting on Mac OS X only though

Comment: Seems related to this thread https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/3862

Comment: @TimL yes I've seen this thread.
I've also tried to break the redirect to 2 separate calls (POST then GET ) with ```maxRedirects: 0  ``` but still the issue persists. I've tried copying the cookie from the POST response to the Get request header, and the expected behavior is getting a response with the same cookie. But the GET call returns a new one instead.